# How to select string row with specified word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a database with comments, and I would like to create another database with just the comment which contains some specific words.

I know there is a function like `contains` but I would like to know how to do this on the entire database and extract only the comments with specific word in order to do some advanced analysis on those specific topics.

Do you have a way to do this ? I'm sure I have already saw that somewhere but I cannot find where.

Here's what's my database look like : [image: database]

I obtained it with BeautifulSoup and this script :

```
import re
import json
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


root_url = 'https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com'
urls = [ '{root}?page={i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in range(1,9) ]

comms = []
notes = []
dates = []

for url in urls: 
    results = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='review-content')

    for container in commentary:

        comm  = container.find('p', class_ = 'review-content__text').text.strip()
        comms.append(comm)

        note = container.find('div', class_ = 'star-rating star-rating--medium').find('img')['alt']
        notes.append(note)

        date_tag = container.div.div.find("div", class_="review-content-header__dates")
        date = json.loads(re.search(r"({.*})", str(date_tag)).group(1))["publishedDate"]

        dates.append(date)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes,
    'dates' : dates
    })

data['comms'] = data['comms'].str.replace('\n', '')

data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates']).dt.date
data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates'])

#print(data.head())
data.to_csv('filetest.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Thanks !

Comment: What sort of "database" do you have?

Comment: Sorry I edit that, my bad

Comment: You have an image of a table? You will need to show us some code instead – how did you end up with that? Is it maybe a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: I put my script in my post to show how I obtained my dataframe. Sorry for the hassle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index the dataframe with a mask you obtain from your `comms` column.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'comms': ['bad', 'good', 'ok'], 'date': ['1', '15', '17']})
>>> df
  comms date
0   bad    1
1  good   15
2    ok   17
>>> df[df.comms.str.contains('good')]
  comms date
1  good   15
>>> df[df.comms.str.contains('d')]
  comms date
0   bad    1
1  good   15
>>>
```

To elaborate, here a mask is a series that maps an index to a True/False condition, like so:

```
>>> m = df.comms.str.contains('good')
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: comms, dtype: bool
```

Then when you use that to index a dataframe, only the rows matching the mask will be selected:

```
>>> df[m]
  comms date
1  good   15
```

### For multiple words:

- You can merge masks with logical operators:

```
>>> df[df.comms.str.contains('go') | df.comms.str.contains('k')]
  comms date
1  good   15
2    ok   17
```

- You can also use the regexp mode for contains:

```
>>> df[df.comms.str.contains('go|k', regex=True)]
  comms date
1  good   15
2    ok   17
```

Comment: How we check for several word with str.contains tho ? You just put one word ? I tried 'word1|word2' but it check either one is here, and I would like both !

Comment: Added an edit. :)

Comment: That's doesn't seems to work, I didn't specified but I would like to keep the comments who contains all the word in contains. Each comment with all the word present in contains. Sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: If you want all comments with both `word1` and `word2`, use an `&` operation: `df.comms.str.contains('word1') & df.comms.str.contains('word2')`

Comment: Ow ok, I tried like this `df6 = df[df['comms_clean'].str.contains('word1 & word2& word3')]` but it didn't seems to work but I see now that my syntax was wrong, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but I would like to know how to select all the comment with words that follow each other. Like that : `data[data['comms'].str.contains('word1 word2 word3')]` ?